# rspec [not found]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am using gem [cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells/) for shopping cart and use following command

```
rails generate cell cart display -e haml
```

it generate cells and give error

```
create  app/cells/cart_cell.rb
invoke  haml
create    app/cells/cart/display.html.haml
error  rspec [not found]
```

i have installed

```
sudo gem install rspec
```

but problem not solved. Can anyb'dy help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please put following line into your Gemfile

```
gem "rspec-cells", ">= 0.1.3", :group => [:test]
```

and run bundle for installing the gem.

Please note, that you have to call

```
rails generate cell cart display -e haml -t rspec
```